# What tools exist in Java that are equivalent to svcutil.exe for .NET?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, interop

What tools exist in Java that are equivalent to svcutil.exe for .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are using svcutil for. To generate client code to access a web service, you would normally use wsimport. To generate a WDSL from server code, you would use wsgen.

Note: There is absolutely no need to use AXIS to publish or consume SOAP based web services in Java, as the other answers seem to imply, unless you have some very specific requirements. Support for plain SOAP clients is included in the standard API and all J2EE compliant application servers must provide server support.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html) has both a [wsdl2java and a java2wsdl tool](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#UsingWSDLWithAxis).

Answer (score 0):

I don't dabble java but I've seen co-workers use [wsdl2java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) to generate proxy stub classes.